# How do I install a package from bionic?

Tags: 18.04, package-management, software-installation, lts

I'm trying to install libpcl. My ubuntu config is as follows,

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

However, I would like to install https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libpcl-dev which is meant for bionic. How can i do so with focal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). You dot not need to do so. The package is available in the *universe* pocket for focal. Install with `sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt install libpcl-dev`.

Comment: It installs the same version that is meant for focal which is lib_pcl1.10  but I want to install lib_pcl1.8.0 which is available only for bionic :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** the method below is overkill, do not use it if unsure. The reinstallation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is simpler, more reproducible and faster.

---

At first enable Source Code repositories from Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`), then get build-dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep pcl sphinx
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential libvtk6-dev libvtk6-qt-dev \
python-all python-setuptools python-six python-docutils python-jinja2 \
python-pytest python-mock python-babel python-alabaster python-imagesize \
python-html5lib python-enum34 python-typing \
python-is-python2

cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-urllib3/python-urllib3_1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-urllib3_1.22-1ubuntu0.18.04.1_all.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/r/requests/python-requests_2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-requests_2.18.4-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb
```

then download PCL source code from 18.04 LTS and compile it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
# Sphinx dependency
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/sphinx_1.6.7.orig.tar.gz
tar -xf  sphinx_1.6.7.orig.tar.gz
cd Sphinx-1.6.7/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/sphinx/sphinx_1.6.7-1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf sphinx_1.6.7-1ubuntu1.debian.tar.xz

DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck debuild -i -us -uc -b
sudo python setup.py install

# PCL itself
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pcl/pcl_1.8.1+dfsg1.orig.tar.gz
tar -xf pcl_1.8.1+dfsg1.orig.tar.gz
cd pcl-pcl-1.8.1/
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pcl/pcl_1.8.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf pcl_1.8.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu2.debian.tar.xz

dpkg-buildpackage -b --no-sign -d
sudo apt-get install ./../*pcl*.deb
```